# Setting ElementStyle of DataGridComboBoxColumn breaks expected behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I've got the following issue and I don't know where my fault is. 
I specified a DataGrid with a DataGridComboBoxColumn and set a simple ElementStyle which should color the text of the non-editing template. The coloring works but the text value itself is always the last edited value.

See the [image](https://abload.de/img/2017-04-1212_49_28-ma5kkc4.png) of the faulty behavior. The red texts should be the same as on the left side. As the objects are the same (see GUID).

I tried set the base style to {x:Static DataGridComboBoxColumn.TextBlockComboBoxStyleKey} and tried to set the TargetType to DataGridComboBoxColumn+TextBlockComboBox (via reflection). Didn't change anything.

I noticed via the Live Property Explorer that the SelectedItem of the DataGridComboBoxColumn+TextBlockComboBox is evaluated for the left grid but not for the right grid. So my assumption is that the binding breaks when setting a style.

Is this a known issue of the WPF DataGrid? Is there any way to resolve this issue without using a DataGridTemplateColumn?

To replicate the issue I attached the source code.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridComboBoxStyleError.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridComboBoxStyleError"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="750" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="_availableCultures" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.AvailableCultures}}" />

        <x:Array x:Key="Items" Type="{x:Type local:TestItem}">
            <local:TestItem CultureName="de" />
            <local:TestItem CultureName="en" />
            <local:TestItem CultureName="ru" />
        </x:Array>

        <Style x:Key="_comboBoxStyle" x:Shared="False" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="_mainGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="ItemsSource via StaticResource" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Default ElementStyle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Specified ElementStyle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _availableCultures}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Culture}" DisplayMemberPath="NativeName" Header="Culture" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _availableCultures}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Culture}" DisplayMemberPath="NativeName" Header="Culture" Width="*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource _comboBoxStyle}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace DataGridComboBoxStyleError
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<CultureInfo> AvailableCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
    }
}
```

TestItem.cs

```
public class TestItem
{
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

    public string CultureName
    {
        get {
            return Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        }
        set {
            Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(value);
        }
    }

    public string Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to resolve this issue without using a DataGridTemplateColumn?

You could set the `CellStyle` instead of setting the `ElementStyle`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _availableCultures}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Culture}" DisplayMemberPath="NativeName" Header="Culture" Width="*">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for simple cases (e. g. Foreground) but what about specifying the `ContentTemplate` for a `ComboBox`?

Comment: Use a DataGridTemplateColumn when the functionality of a DataGridComboBoxColumn doesn't suits your needs for any reason.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer your issue has been solved: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow